# Injected service is undefined

Tags: angular

I have the following `HandleService`:

```
@Injectable()
export class HandleService {

  constructor(private notificationService: NotificationService) {
  }

  success(message: string) {
    this.notificationService.printSuccessMessage(message);
  }

  error(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      this.notificationService.printErrorMessage(error.error.message);
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      this.notificationService.printErrorMessage(error.message);
      console.error(
        `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
        `body was: ${error.error}`);
    }
    // return an observable with a user-facing error message
    return throwError(
      'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
  };
}
```

And thats the used `NotificationService`:

```
@Injectable()
export class NotificationService {
  private _notification: any = alertify;

  constructor() {
  }

  openConfirmationDialog(message: string, okCallback: () => any) {
    this._notification.confirm(message, function (e) {
      if (e) {
        okCallback();
      } else {
      }
    });
  }

  printSuccessMessage(message: string) {

    this._notification.success(message);
  }

  printErrorMessage(message: string) {
    this._notification.error(message);
  }

  openAlertDialog(message: string) {
    this._notification.alert(message);
  }
}
```

I use `HandleService` like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomerService {

constructor(public http: HttpClient, private authService: AuthService,
              private handleService: HandleService) {
  }

deleteCustomer(customer: Customer): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.delete(BASE_URL + customer.id, this.authService.setHeaders('application/json'))
      .pipe(
        tap(() => this.handleService.success(`Deleted customer: ${customer.name}`)),
        catchError(this.handleService.error)
      );
  }
}
```

So when everything works fine `this.handleService.success('Deleted customer: ${customer.name}')` is executed which works as expected. If an error occurs, `this.handleService.error` is executed, but it does not print the error message, instead i get the following error `cannot read property 'printErrorMessage' of undefined`. So `notificationService` in my `handleService` is undefined here, but why? Its injected in the constructor and it works correctly on the `succes`-method. Why isnt it working in the `error`-method?

Comment: Maybe you should add the Module declaration to your post so people stop telling you to provide the services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess:
The scope of `this.handleService.error` is different when passed as a parameter and not executed (inside of your `deleteCustomer` function).

Replace it with `this.handleService.error.bind(this)`

Answer (score 1):

Have you had your service in your app.module.ts ?

```
providers: [HandleService,NotificationService],
```

Comment: It will give error if not provided. It won't undefined I think.

Comment: Ye, it is provided. Like i said, its working correctly for the `succes` method which wouldnt be the case if there was a provider issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add service on providers array in App.module.ts, or you can use:

```
 @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add any provider to app.module.ts

Just add decorator ahead your service class

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CustomerService
```

same for HandleService

Comment: Only if it is *appropriate* that the services in question be provided at root, of course.